# Effect of stirring and shaking on chemical kinetics

Tags: kinetics, rate-equation

Why don't we take the effects of stirring and shaking on the rates of chemical reactions? While studying chemical kinetics, I've seen that the rates depend on the concentrations of various species, temperature, pressure, etc. But I've never seen an equation taking into account the mechanical stirring, shaking and geometry of the beaker, presumably because these things are hard to experimentally measure and form a physical model which incorporates these things. For example, if the iodine clock reaction changes its rates due to stirring, every time I do the reaction, I shall get different times for colour changes. *Then why do chemical kinetics equations make sense at all?*

Comment: Stirring and shaking provide some kinetic energy to the system. It increases slightly its temperature and the reaction rate. Very slightly.

Comment: @Maurice I don't think that slight increase in temperature changes anything. It's probably that stirring mixes the reactants well, and prevents localized concentration deficits.

Comment: @Maurice we can keep the reaction setup on a thermostat in keep the temperature constant. We would still see a rate change.

Comment: For a homogeneous reaction, as the mixing is increased, the rate will approach the theoretical rate. For aqueous reactions of fairly dilute reactants that happen slowly enough to measure kinetics, a “normal” amount of stirring is sufficient to be very close to that theoretical value and differences in rates between mildly different experimental setups are negligible

Comment: For fast reactions there are special setups to achieve mixing that is rapid enough to eliminate mixing as a kinetic factor

Comment: Apparently, shaken or stirred ethanolic solutions can be differentiated by bond. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaken,_not_stirred